# Quarkus @ApplicationScoped working in dev run, but not when running the built jar

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus

I have an abstract class, which has an implementation with `@ApplicationScoped`.

This works without an issue in `quarkusDev`, but when running the built app, it complains of a function that I have implemented in the abstract class.

`java.lang.VerifyError: class me.l3n.[...].GoodReadsCrawlerService_ClientProxy overrides final method me.l3n.bot.[...].CrawlerService .parseHtml(Ljava/lang/String;Lkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object;`

```
abstract class CrawlerService {
    protected suspend infix fun parseHtml(url: String): Document {
        /* ... */
    }
}

@ApplicationScoped
class GoodReadsCrawlerService: CrawlerService() {
    /* implements other abstract functions of base class */
}
```

Note that I'm not even overriding that `parseHtml()` function.

But if I change the `GoodReadsCrawlerService` to `Singleton()`, OR add the `open` keyword to `parseHtml`, it works just fine in any case.

The actual example can be found in [my repo](https://github.com/LegendL3n/Pensador/commit/9a499367f08fefb8f75e408677209a6e0f504659).

I'd assume the ClientProxy is treating the abstract class as an interface, so implements all functions for proxying, assuming they're all abstract.

But why doesn't this happen in `quarkusDev`?

Comment: The reason is that dev mode automatically adds a proxy to trace calls. In any case, this sounds like something we can improve on. Can you please open an issue?

Comment: @geoand but then it would not work in dev mode, right? The problem seems to be in the proxy's behavior (which I don't know how different it is in each mode)

Comment: You can turn off the tracing of calls using `quarkus.arc.dev-mode.monitoring-enabled=false`

Comment: @geoand which side effects would that bring?

Comment: It will disable the request tracking feature in the Arc card of the dev console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [small issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23282) on Quarkus itself, fixed in 2.7.1-final.